# TFS 2010 and Sharepoint (Licensing)

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

If I use MOSS 2007 or Sharepoint Services 3.0 with TFS do I need a license or is there an implicit license with TFS, like there is for SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a license for MOSS, but Sharepoint Services 3.0 are part of Windows and don't require a separate license to use. TFS only requires WSS to run. The stack looks like this:

```
        WSS
       /   \
    MOSS   TFS
```

Answer (score 0):

WSS 3.0 comes free with Windows Server 2005/2008, MOSS always requires a separate license. TFS doesn't grant you any kind of SharePoint licensing afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Ray - as others have said you need a license for MOSS beyond your Windows Server and TFS licenses, but not WSS 3.0 for ***TFS 2008***.  TFS 2010 does not require WSS or MOSS at all if you have another site or portal solution (i.e. FlexWiki, Zen, Pivotal Tracker, etc).